# Query to get a subforms text value from the main form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to select/update/add/delete stuff from a textbox in a sub-form which is in my main form. I need a way to access the said textboxes value and interact with it. This code is from a search box I created.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
  Dim SQL As String

  SQL = "SELECT row.product_id, row.product_name, row.impacode, row.product_description, row.explanation, row.mu, row.category_name, row.Quantity " _
    & "FROM row " _
    & "Where product_name LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
    & "OR category_name LIKE '*" & Me.txtKeywords & "*' " _
    & "ORDER BY row.impacode "

   Me.SubCatalog.Form.RecordSource = SQL
   Me.SubCatalog.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

[image]

I want to access the quantity textbox, get the number, and update the table or remove it etc...

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: So, whats your Problem?

Comment: Yes i need a way to get the number from the quantity textbox and add it to the datatable by pressing a button

Comment: the quantity textbox is in a subform contained in my main form how do i access its properties?

Comment: `TextBoxValue = Forms!YourSubform!YourTextbox` Then make an insert statement with this parameter

Comment: Don't expect people to do all your job. Try some things, then ask for particular issue. Not "how to do my whole project". Have fun and read [ask] please.

Comment: Your SQL statement gets you halfway there.  Use that same SQL statement to retrieve a "recordset" and use that to get your [Quantity] that you can use in an UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statement.